memory allocation for several large vectors
I am sequentially processing several large vectors and trying to free memory but at some point getting memory allocation error. I fill one vector (vec1), use it, free memory of it, and starting fill second vector (vec2), where I am getting memory error. I can not understand why, if I use another vector, and "free memory" of previous vector.
std::vector <float> vec1;
std::vector <float> vec2;

for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) //---filling vec1 with 432M elements
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
        {
            std::vector <float> sub_vec(48, 0); //---filling with some float, lets say 0
            vec1.insert(vec1.end(), sub_vec.begin(), sub_vec.end());
        }
     }
}

//---doing something with vec1
std::vector <float>().swap(vec1); //---trying to free memory

for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) //---filling vec2 with 432M elements
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 300; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 300; j++)
        {
            std::vector <float> sub_vec(48, 0); //---filling with some float, lets say 0
            vec2.insert(vec2.end(), sub_vec.begin(), sub_vec.end()); /// EDITED here ----at some point getting error here, not enough memory
        }
    }
}

Tried free vector by shrink_to_fit(). With smaller amounts of elements works fine.

You need to provide a minimal, reproducible example if you want meaningful help

std::vector <float>().swap(vec1); What exactly do you expect that to do?? At best that's a NOP. Post a [mcve] as required here please.

Side note: shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request and is often ignored.

@πάνταῥεῖ Its a binding way to blow away the allocation space of a vector.

If your error line is really vec2.insert(vec1.end(), sub_vec.begin(), sub_vec.end()); then you have a typo.  you are using vec1.end() but vec1 is a blank object.  Most likely it should have been vec2.insert(vec2.end(), sub_vec.begin(), sub_vec.end());

This program looks like a great way to induce memory fragmentation.

You should call .reserve() with the full number of elements on vec1 and vec2 before inserting anything in the vectors. Otherwise, you may end up allocating extra memory which may be too much if your executable is 32-bit.

Lifetime control with scope is much easier; use an extra pair of curly braces ({}) around your code, and all automatic objects inside will die when code execution exits the scope. No need for gymnastics like swap.

Even if you free all the memory of the first vector, sub_vec might eventually chop off a piece of that, and make the block too small.

Thank you all, guys, I figured out that the problem was in another point (when I am trying to put this big vectors to glBufferData outside of this code). Anyway thank you!

Do you compile your application as a 64Bit Application? Your vectors should exceed the 4GB limit of 32Bit applications.

The problem was in another part of code (when I am trying to put this big vectors to glBufferData outside of this code). std::vector ().swap(vec1) function saved some memory for me, but eventually I have got same problem of exceeding memory. Using 64Bit app. Probably I need to only few that big vector when drawing OpenGL scene, or use more RAM.

You don't have 50 rep yet, so you can't comment, which would have been better. You can always edit your questions to add updates which I think would have been better in this case.
